# Is there possible way to add base url for imports in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs, vue.js

Normal way adding imports:

`import Sample from ‘../../../components/signup’`

I need to imports without front dots and slashes:

`import Component from ‘components/signup’`

Can I add base url for imports to solve this problem? Is it the right way? Or if there a solution please leave the answer below.

Comment: If using webpack, see [resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve)

Answer (score 4):

If you use [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve), you can add the below code snippet into your `webpack.config.js`

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
     components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `jsconfig.json` file in your root directory
2. Place the code below to the file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

3. Restart your npm script